# Getting the original Object form an Annotation object

Tags: java, annotations

I am in a situation where I am getting all the annotations of a class using

```
final Annotation[] annotations = declaringClass.getAnnotations();
```

Now I know that one of the annotations is of type MyAnnotation which has the following format

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {

boolean state() default true;
```

I would like to be able to get the value set for the parameter state, how do I do this? Annotation seems to be a proxy and not the actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for that particular annotation, you can get it directly like this:

```
MyAnnotation a = declaringClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
boolean state = a.state();
```

If you specifically want it from your array, just cast it:

```
MyAnnotation a = (MyAnnotation)annotations[i];
boolean state = a.state();
```